# Hide div dynamically onclick on other div

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bookRetr(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("more-info").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("more-info").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","showbook.php?id="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

<div class="bookProp" id="one" onClick="bookRetr(this.id)">
    <div class="booknoHolder" id="in">&nbsp;01&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="bookProp" id="two" onClick="bookRetr(this.id)">
    <div class="booknoHolder" id="in">&nbsp;02&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="bookProp" id="three" onClick="bookRetr(this.id)">
    <div class="booknoHolder" id="in">&nbsp;03&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

This script runs fine and does the work which I wanted, to load book info and load them to the id `more-info`. But I want to also hide/remove the div class `booknoHolder`  when I click on the div class `bookProp`. I tried with a few jQuery codes but nothing is working. To mention that the div class `bookProp` is actually generated by a PHP while loop so the number of entries will be dynamic.

Comment: id should be unique and you are using same id.

Comment: There are same `id="in"` on the div with `booknoHolder` class

Comment: yes..but i can make it dynamic if you can give me a suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you are using jQuery but i don't see any jQuery in your code. But if you want to hide some elements in jQuery, you can do this :

```
$('.booknoHolder').hide();
```

If you want to hide the `booknoHolder` elements when you click on a `bookProp`, just do this :

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.bookProp', function() {
        $(this).find('.booknoHolder').hide();
    });
});
```

You can find more information here : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I tried your code but when i click on one bookProp div all the other booknoHolder gets removed. I want that corresponding div booknoHolder to remove.

Comment: use $(this).find('.bookHolder').hide(). ahh just saw the edit

Answer (score 0):

For a jQuery solution, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bookRetr(str) {
        // Get the HTML via AJAX
        $.get('showbook.php?id=' + str, function(html) {
            $("#more-info").html(html);
        });

        // Assuming .bookProp is appended inside #more-info
        $('#more-info').on('click', '.bookProp', function() {
            $('.booknoHolder', $(this)).hide();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bookRetr(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("more-info").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 

        $("#" + str + " .booknoHolder").hide();
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this method helpful

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("more-info").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                if(str=="one") { 
                document.getElementById("one").style.display="block";
                document.getElementById("two").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("three").style.display="none";
}
                if(str=="two") { 
 document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("two").style.display="block";
                document.getElementById("three").style.display="none";
}
                if(str=="three") {
 document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("two").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("three").style.display="block";
 }
            }
        }
```

Comment: My div are dynamically generated by a php script, so how can I code in this way?